# Initialization 91 stuck of Supermicro OEM (HPE) GPU server

Tags: supermicro

I just set up HPE SX40 (Supermicro SYS-1029GQ-TVRT).

The system stuck on boot with "initializing ... 91".
I tried some crude test like remove all memory, and got relevant error message.

So,
1)removed all pcie cards (including NVIDIA SXM2 adapter boards) and boot
-> no luck

2)Followed FAQ to reset CMOS (https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=18922)
-> no luck

3)Direct bios update (https://www.supermicro.com/support/faqs/faq.cfm?faq=20491)
-> no luck at all.

Any comments in [Supermicro stuck on 91](https://serverfault.com/questions/675400/supermicro-stuck-on-91)
also didn't work.

Does anybody knows what 91 exactly means for X11DGQ (the board built by supermicro)?

I am suspicious about the number of gpus (I have only one V100 gpu, so connected in SXM2 slot 3 following HP configuration of two cards (slot 3 and slot 2, for cpu1 and cpu2), but it still make no sense about 1), since same 91 error shows up after removing all pcie connections.

Answer (score 0):

All above trials are no-luck, but after struggling for three days, I decided to disassemble all and clean-reassemble.

It boot!!!
I figured out something was wrong in cpu2.
cpu issue also might cause 91! since it's pcie lane related : )